# How to define and access local variable in Typoscript 2 (Neos)?

Tags: neoscms, typoscript2

I have created a custom NodeType "Events" with a custom TS2 file in Neos, but I guess it is more a general question about Typoscript 2.

```
prototype(Some.Namespace:Events) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Document) {
    ...

    sortOrder = ${request.arguments.sortOrder  == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'}
    otherVariable = ${sortOrder}

    ...
}
```

Of course this is simplified to focus on the issue:

I want to assign the value of the variable `sortOrder` (which is "asc" or "desc") to another variable named `otherVariable`.

How can I do that? I cannot access the value using `${sortOrder}`, which returns always NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `this` as below and `{otherVariable}` in your fluid template will work. Flush cache in case you sill have `NULL`.

```
sortOrder = ${request.arguments.sortOrder  == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'}
otherVariable = ${this.sortOrder}
```

Comment: I added somewhat similar question about parent variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930060/fusion-typoscript-2-how-to-access-a-variable-from-a-parent-object