# Fusion (Typoscript 2): How to access a variable from a parent object?

Tags: neoscms, typoscript2

This is sort of a follow-up question for [How to define and access local variable in Typoscript 2 (Neos)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614063/how-to-define-and-access-local-variable-in-typoscript-2-neos)

If I define a local variable, called `myLocalVar` in the example below, how can I access it from other objects, in this case from `Neos.Fusion:Case`?

```
prototype(Some.Namespace:SomeNodeType) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Content) {
    myLocalVar = ${String.split(q(node).property('example'), '/', 2)}

    myResult = Neos.Fusion:Case {
        a = Neos.Fusion:Matcher {
            condition = ${???.myLocalVar[0] == 'aaa'}
            renderer = 'first part is aaa'
        }
        b = Neos.Fusion:Matcher {
            condition = ${???.myLocalVar[0] == 'bbb'}
            renderer = 'first part is bbb'
        }
    }
}
```

In this concrete example: How can I access `myLocalVar` from inside `Neos.Fusion:Matcher`?

The part in question is the condition: `condition = ${???.myLocalVar[0] == 'aaa'}`

Comment: Small hint: If you use `Neos.Fusion:Case`, you don't have to write `Neos.Fusion:Matcher` everytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your myLocalVar as context variable:

```
@context.myLocalVar = ${String.split(q(node).property('example'), '/', 2)}
```

the context is inherited by all nesting objects, so you can just access the value like this

```
a = Neos.Fusion:Matcher {
    condition = ${myLocalVar[0] == 'aaa'}
    renderer = 'first part is aaa'
}
```

Comment: "the context is inherited by all nesting objects": I was missing exactly this bit of information. I was wandering about the exact role of @context. Thank you.